# As a new collaborator, how to add code that is very different from master branch?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a git repository of a code base. I have been working on this code base for about a week and I just added a new collaborator. This new collaborator has too, been working on the same code but because we did not version control since last week, our two projects look somewhat different (some added files and folders) and as well as code changes to existing files as well.

I tried having him make a new branch, then overwriting that branch with his code, then pulling from master but was having issues with this? It says it is already up to date with master.

How should I go about merging our two code bases together. I know there will doubtlessly be some conflicts but if it will actually let me resolve them and merge correctly, I'll be happy.

Comment: I won't give an answer because your question is too vague.  `It says it is already up to date with master` ... this is likely because your colleague never did a `git fetch`, so his local Git thinks it is up to date, when in fact it is not.  Basically, you guys should commit your work, and then merge/rebase it onto the shared remote branch.

Answer (score 0):

The best way here would be identifying the common commit from which both of you started. Then you can create two branches for each of you:

```
git branch collaborator1-branch <commit-id>
git branch collaborator2-branch <commit-id>
```

Or in case one of you already committed the changes into `master` then skip the one of the branch. Anyway then copy the work-tree into newly created branch:

```
git checkout collaborator1-branch
cp -R ../my-temporary-snapshot/. .
git add -A
git commit -m "message" .
```

And finally merge the latest changes from master into current branch or vice versa:

```
git merge master
# or later
git checkout master
git merge collaborator1-branch
```